# Centering divs - Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css

Well, divide the piece of content in two divs, col-md-6, only that they are not centralized in relation to the site, despite being in the center, they are placed on the left, leaving the right side a little empty. Follows the code of divs.

```
<div class="content">

    <div class="container clearfix">
                        <div class="col-md-6 configdiv">
                            <img src="/layout/images/imagem1.png" />
                            <h5>TITULO 1</h5>
                            <p>
                            Oi, tudo bem? Oi, tudo bem? Oi, tudo bem?
                            Oi, tudo bem?
                            Oi, tudo bem?
                            <p>
                            <div>
                                <img src="/layout/images/iconemail.png" />
                                <img src="/layout/images/iconefb.png" />
                                <img src="/layout/images/iconett.png" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 configdiv">
                            <img src="/layout/images/imagem2.png" />
                            <h5>TITULO 2</h5>
                            <p>
                                Oi, tudo bem?
                            <p>
                            <div>
                            <img src="/layout/images/iconemail.png" />
                            <img src="/layout/images/iconefb.png" />
                            <img src="/layout/images/iconett.png" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

And the CSS is this:

```
   .configdiv {border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
           margin-right: 28px;
           margin-bottom: 25px;
           padding: 10px;
```

Remembering these two divs al-md-6, are a side by side, I want to be centered over the screen! Content content:

```
   Content----------------------------------------------------*/
    #content {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #FFF;
}

 #content p { line-height: 1.8; }

.content-wrap {
position: relative;
padding: 80px 0;
}

#content .container { position: relative; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your columns, `.col-md-6`, in a `<div>` with a `.row` class. The way Bootstrap works you're required to wrap all columns inside a row.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```